# modify XML tags with specific pattern by Regex tools

Tags: xml, regex, perl, sed, awk

I have a large xml file with a bunch of database table definitions that look like this:

```
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
```

I would like to replace the end bracket in each matching line (not all lines start with `table name=""`) so that the original line is retained, but `slonyId="number"` is appended before the `>`.  To make things a bit more complex, I'd like the slonyId number to be incremented, starting at 0, so that if I have 1000 table definitions, the first one looks like:

```
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="0">
```

And the last one looks like:

```
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyId="999">
```

What is the best approach to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you recognizing the line if `table name=` ins't guaranteed to be there? Is the only identifying feature `>`?

Comment: each line I care about starts with "table name="  There are many other lines in the file, but some start with "index name" or something else.  I don't need to modify these lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding solution from JS:

```
awk -F'>' '/table name/{$NF="slonyid="q x++ q FS}1' q='"' inputFile
```

Try this:

```
awk -F'>' '/table name/{print $(NF-1)" slonyid""=""\""NR-1"\""">"}' inputFile
```

Adding test:

```
$ cat temp.txt
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>


$ awk -F'>' '/table name/{print $(NF-1)" slonyid""=""\""NR-1"\""">"}' temp.txt
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="0">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="1">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="2">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="3">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="4">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="5">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="6">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="7">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="8">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="9">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="10">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="11">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="12">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="13">
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here slonyid="14">
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand this command, and I'm not sure how it works.  I think -F identifies > as a field separator.  Could you elaborate?  The fact that I don't see "slonyID=" anywhere in your solution makes me think that your solution won't solve my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2533865 I have added a test, hope that helps.

Comment: @user2533865: You're welcome. Please do remember to accept the answer if it has helped you solve your problem :)

Comment: @Amit Couple of suggestions. Using `NR` for lines that may not appear on every line is not useful. Using a variable will help. Also, there are too many quotes. You can create a variable and call it inside your `awk` script. Something like: `awk -F'>' '/table name/{$NF="slonyid="q x++ q FS}1' q='"' xmlfile`. Using a variable will ensure that it gets incremented in order even if lines appear periodically. One more thing, we need to add `regex` so it only affects lines with table names and not all lines.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed = file|sed 'N;s/\n/\t/;/\S\+\s\+table name/!d'|sed =|sed 'N;s/\n/\t/;s/\(\S\+\)\s\+\([^>]\+\)>/\2 slonyid="\1">/;s#\(\S\+\)\s\+\(.*\)#\1 s/.*/\2/#'|sed -f - file
```

---

Pure `sed` solution with 4 pipes.

```
$cat file
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text AAA here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text ZZZ here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text BBB here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text CCC here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text DDD here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text ZZZ here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text EEE here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text FFF here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text ZZZ here>

$sed = file|sed 'N;s/\n/\t/;/\S\+\s\+table name/!d'|sed =|sed 'N;s/\n/\t/;s/\(\S\+\)\s\+\([^>]\+\)>/\2 slonyid="\1">/;s#\(\S\+\)\s\+\(.*\)#\1 s/.*/\2/#'|sed -f - file
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text AAA here slonyid="1">
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text ZZZ here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text BBB here slonyid="2">
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text CCC here slonyid="3">
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text DDD here slonyid="4">
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text ZZZ here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text EEE here slonyid="5">
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text FFF here slonyid="6">
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text XXX here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text YYY here>
index name="dbname.tablename" lots of text ZZZ here>
```

Comment: starting number is `1` instead of `0` - imo this can't be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This perl one-liner will do the trick if I understand your question correctly:

```js
perl -pi.bak -e 'BEGIN {$count=0}; if (/^table name=/) { s/^(table name=.*)>$/$1 slonyId="$count">/; $count++}' inputFile.xml
```

These options tell perl to loop over the given filenames and creates a backup with the name "orig_filname.bak":

```js
perl -pi.bak -e
```

This initializes the `$count` variable:

```js
BEGIN {$count=0};
```

This increments count and does the replacement you asked for:

```js
if (/^table name=/) { s/^(table name=.*)>$/$1 slonyId="$count">/; $count++}
```

Then just provide the list of filenames at the end:

```js
inputFile.xml
```

This is not a very robust solution and could break if any lines in your file don't match the description you gave above, but it should work for your problem.

I think I'm too new to comment on the other solutions directly, but in my tests FDinoff's solution will add the slonyId to a line that looks like this:

```js
not a table name="dbname.tablename" lots of text here>
```

And Amit's solution will add the slonyId to every line, not just lines that begin with "table name".

Answer (score 0):

vim solution

Use global to find `table name=` in a line. and replace the `>` on that line with `slonyId="number">` You can do this by using using the following two line.

```
:let i = 0
:g/^table name=/s/>/\='slonyId="' . i . '"' . submatch(0)/ | let i=i+1
```

The first line initializes `i` to 0. The substitute takes the first element of that list every time it does a match and uses string concatenation to generate the correct string. Then after the substitute `i` will be incremented. So that the next substitute gets the next number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You should never edit XML files using line-by-line string manipulations. XML isn't structured like that. Always use a proper XML parser, like Perl's `XML::LibXML`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('/path/to/input.xml');

my $i = 0;
$_->setAttribute('slonyId', $i++) for $xml->findnodes('//table');

$xml->toFile('/path/to/output.xml')
```

Comment: The snippet the OP posted isn't valid XML, so if you tried with just that it's unsurprising you got an error.

Comment: But it is XML. Or at least the OP claimed it was.

Comment: I said *shouldn't*, not *can't*. And it's actually pretty simple: if your input is XML: use an XML parser. If your input isn't XML: use whatever else is appropriate. Since only the OP can clarify whether or not the file is valid XML I'm not going to continue this pointless argument.